# Using the nasaAPI with the example arguments

Tags: json, hyperlink

https://rapidapi.com/dimas/api/NasaAPI?endpoint=apiendpoint_b4e69440-f966-11e7-809f-87f99bda0814getEarthAssets

I've seen the documentation, which gives "50.37, 26.56" as an example of how to format coordinates. The problem is that when I fill in those coordinates in the linked application, it responds with this:

```
{
   "callback":"error",
   "contextWrites":{
      "to":{
         "status_code":"JSON_VALIDATION",
         "status_msg":"Syntax error. Incorrect input JSON. Please, check fields with JSON input."
      }
   }
}
```

I have a sneaking suspition that its broken, but if anyone knows how I could get it to work, that would be great. Its also worth mentioning that I've gotten other parts of the same API, such as getPictureOfTheDay, to work, and the ones I've gotten to work don't require arguments.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put a empty json object in the post request.
I dont know why they made it a post request